# Power bi service not available in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I am trying to add Power BI API in Azure. I can't see power BI service API option in Azure.
[image]
Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is the one named "Power BI Service" from your screenshot. But since it is grayed out, it means that you already added it. If you want to grant permissions for it, go to "Required permissions", select if from the API list bellow (don't try to add it - it should be already in the list) and click "Grant permissions" button above.